# Laptop Keyboard & Mouse Not Working After Update

Tags: keyboard, mouse, laptop, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon that I recently performed a routine update on, which required a restart - so maybe updating the Linux kernel or something but I'm not too sure because I wasn't, like, updating my version of Ubuntu or anything. After restarting, I'm not able to access keyboard or mouse capabilities from the built-in hardware *or* external USB devices. I'm assuming that I will need to boot in using a live recovery USB or something, but I'm not entirely certain what steps to perform once I've gotten into the machine. Can someone help provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and/or solve this problem?

Edit: the keyboard works when I'm in the BIOS menus. I have never used GRUB with this machine, so I'm not sure if it's available or if so how to access it.

Final edit before I grab the handful of important local files on the machine and just reinstall the OS: I finally got a live recovery going, which took a surprising amount of time, and the peripherals work just fine in the temporary OS. Are there any commands I can run to try to fix whatever firmware (?) was borked in the update? I toggled some settings in the BIOS that seemed related, but nothing really seemed to change.

Comment: I had a similar problem after upgrade, for me it was the graphics card that was put out of operation. In the BIOS, I found some emergency mode (don't remember if it's called that or has another name). After booting with that and then switching to normal mode (without rebooting) it works. Well, as long as I don't restart the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose to reinstall the operating system through a recovery disk.

Answer (score 0):

From GRUB boot into recovery mode and try:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

This will install drivers for keyboard and mouse

Comment: As I said in my question, I was not sure if GRUB was installed or if it was how I would have accessed it. In any case, the problem has already been "solved" but thank you for your suggestion - hopefully it will help someone else.